# How to use various culture specific resource files on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website which currently uses EN-US and I also have resource file for french. what code should I need to write to make the application use the french version of the resource file.

The site is a commerce server and share point site that uses .NET

Any code examples would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options.  Option one is at the application level.  You could do this in the system.web section of the web.config:

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR" />
```

Another option is on the page:

```
<%@Page Culture="fr-FR" Language="C#" %>
```

or by thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the main resource file's feature as the ability to retrieve localized strings according to the culture specified in the url through code such as:

```
localresourcestring = (String)GetLocalResourceObject("username")  
//will retrieve the localized string for username from your resx (according to the resx's name)!
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) a great place to start, including a Walkthrough and such..

Answer (score 1):

I would set the language at the `Application_BeginRequest()` global event in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    // Get the CultureInfo object that contains the French language specification
    CultureInfo frenchCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");

    // Set the language the current thread uses (per-user)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = frenchCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = frenchCulture;
}
```

Hope it helps.